# Django 3 - Passed variable in views.py not accessible in web form like other vars

Tags: python, django

Newbie to Django here - I have a list of DB entries that I want to be able to cycle through one at a time and currently I am working on loading the first object by its ID. The form renders fine, but other vars aren't accessible as expected - am I missing something in the code?

views.py

```
def ticket_edit(request):
    updateform = TicketForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if updateform.is_valid():
            ticket = Ticket.objects.update(
                ticketID=updateform.cleaned_data['ticketID']
            )
            ticket.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
         else:
            print("FORM NOT YET VALID: Awaiting form.is_valid()")
            updateform = TicketForm()
    #--Get list of ticketIDs---------------
    def ticketID_listGet(): 
        tickets = Ticket.objects.all()
        ticketIDList = []
        for ticket in tickets:
            aTicketID = ticket.appTicketID
            ticketIDList.append(aTicketID)
        return ticketIDList

    tList = ticketID_listGet()
    tFirst = str(tList[0])
    print('TicketIDs: ', tList, tFirst)

    return render(request,'authentication/ticket-edit.html',{
        "has_error": False,
        "updateform": updateform,
        "tFirst": tFirst
    })
```

ticket-edit.html

```
        <div class="container" style="border-style:none">
            <form action="." method="POST" id="ticket-update-form" style="border-style:none">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-control" style="border-style:none">
                            {{ updateform.ticketID.label_tag }}
                            {{ updateform.ticketID }}
                            {{ tFirst }}                 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am not getting errors when using {{ tFirst }}, it's just being ignored as if unrecognized. Ultimately I am trying to determine how to retrieve the existing ticketIDs and the first ticketID as vars and then cycle through them with buttons that set the value in the web form's {{ updateform.ticketID }) widget - am I making this more difficult than necessary?

Comment: What is the output of `print('TicketIDs: ', tList, tFirst)`?

Comment: @JohnGordon TicketIDs:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 1    - the vars are returned in the console without issue on page get, so my expectation was that they would be available to reference in {{ updateform.var }}